# setOnClickListener doesnt work when clicking the button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button

So I am trying to build a small calculator app in Android Studio using Kotlin.
When the user presses the add button both the numbers should be calculated and displayed in the textView but when I press the button nothing happens. Please help me resolve this.

I am getting unresolved references error please have a look

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(activity_main)
    addButton.setOnClickListener {
        addition()
    }
}
fun addition() {
    val num1Text = numberFirst.toString()
    val num2Text = numberSecond.toString()
    // Check if the input is empty
    if (num1Text.isEmpty() || num2Text.isEmpty()) {
        resultView = "Please enter valid numbers".toInt()
        return
    }
    // Convert the input to integers and perform addition
    val num1 = num1Text.toInt()
    val num2 = num2Text.toInt()
    val sum = num1 + num2
    resultView = "Result: $sum".toInt() // Display the result in 
    the TextView
   }
  }
```

This is the activity main file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Simple Calculator App"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<EditText
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter first number"
    android:id="@+id/numberFirst"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp" />

<EditText
    android:ems="5"
    android:hint="Enter second number"
    android:id="@+id/numberSecond"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:textSize="25dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this>

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val addButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.addButton) // Button element with ID addButton

    addButton.setOnClickListener {
        addition()
    }
}

fun addition() {
    val num1Text = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.numberFirst).text.toString() // EditText with ID numberFirst
    val num2Text = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.numberSecond).text.toString() // EditText with ID numberSecond
    val resultView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultView) // TextView with ID resultView

    if (num1Text.isEmpty() || num2Text.isEmpty()) {
        resultView.text = "Please enter valid numbers"
        return
    }

    val num1 = num1Text.toInt()
    val num2 = num2Text.toInt()
    val sum = num1 + num2

    resultView.text = "Result: $sum"
   }
 }
```

Comment: I cannot seem to use addButton.setOnClickListener It shows unresolved references

Comment: that depends on what you called the variable. in your case it should be buttonAdd

Comment: I have edited and added the whole xml and main activity code in the question. Please have a look

Comment: yes, you should get the ids of you xml elements. my solution included only the relevant code as the other elements id is up to you. my bad ill update my answer

Comment: Hello, thanks to your code I find the unresolved reference problem but now when I press the add button my program crashes. Please help this is so hard haha

Comment: I'm on it, give me few mins

Comment: Check my updated answer please.

Comment: Omg thank you very much it is working now. You are a life saver brother

Comment: Ofc, happy to help. please mark my answer as solved to help the community